# Rails: find_by_sql uses the wrong ID

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am using the following Ruby code:

```
sql = "SELECT *  FROM
       conversations
       INNER JOIN member_users ON member_users.conversation_id = conversations.id


       WHERE conversations.id = #{conversation.id}
       AND member_users.user_id = #{user.id}"

    cs = Conversation.find_by_sql(sql)
```

The query returns a single row. But, find_by_sql is returning the Conversation with the ID of the member_user, not the ID of the Conversation. This is because there are two "id" columns in the result, and find_by_sql seems to be using the wrong one.

Is there any way to prevent this without using SELECT conversations.* instead of SELECT *?

Why does this happen - why doesn't Rails use the first ID column it comes across? Is it because the row is returned in a hash?

More generally, in SQL - is there a way to differentiate between different columns with the same name? Or are these meant to be equivalent? I often get confused when doing joins which result in several "id" cols.

Thanks,
Louise

Comment: It very much looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you using SQL instead of [arel](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)? Why are you selecting `Conversation` you already have instance of?

Comment: The real query is much more complex. It's very easy to write in SQL, very hard to write in arel. I tend to use pure SQL because a) I write in a lot of different languages, and don't want to learn a lot of different ORMs, and b) I write a lot of queries which are too slow when using an ORM. Recent example: ten minutes using SQLAlchemy bulk insert, seven seconds using crafted SQL string.

Answer (score 4):

If you do a join in a `find_by_sql` query, ActiveRecord sometimes mixes up identically-named columns from the tables. You can hint ActiveRecord to correctly map by changing the `SELECT` clause to only include the table columns you are interested in.

So to fix your problem, change your query to begin with

```
"SELECT conversations.* FROM conversations ..."
```

Comment: From my question: "Is there any way to prevent this without using SELECT conversations.* instead of SELECT *?"

What if I want to return several columns from different tables after a join?

Answer (score 0):

I would find it like so

```
class MemberUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation_user

  scope :users, ->(*u) {
    where(user_id: u.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }

  scope :conversations, -> (*c) {
    where(conversation_id: c.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }
end

  Conversation.joins(:member_users).merge(MemberUser.users(user))
```

As for your direct question, why are you trying to find the conversation when you already have it?

Comment: This query has been greatly simplified for this post.